# Actix serving on two ports?

Tags: rust, port, actix-web

I want Actix to bind and serve HTTP at two TCP ports at once.

How to do this?

Will two `App::new()` in Tokio `select!` macro work as expected?

I'd prefer to have just one `App`. Then, can I somehow specify port like I specify path through decorating a method?

Comment: Well, what did YOU try already?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done instead grouping APIs into subdirectories:

- `/api1/...`
- `/api2/...`

and serving them to separate ports (or domains) through a reverse proxy, such as Nginx.